# Lag using Xlib/X11 event handling in C

Tags: c, events, x11, xlib

Beginner user of C here.

I'm trying to build a library in C using X11/Xlib so I can use it just for little projects and I'm running into a problem when trying to handle events to get input(button presses and key presses) from the user. It works fine for a while and then it starts to build up a significant lag over time.

Right now what I have is my program checking if there is an event waiting and if there is, retrieving it.

I think that my problem right now is that the events are getting stored in memory and its bogging down the program. But that's just a total guess.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: Forgot code (I knew I forgot something)

The two functions in question are:

```
int event_waiting()
{
    XEvent event;

    if(XCheckMaskEvent(dspy,-1,&event)) {
        if(event.type==KeyPress) {
            XPutBackEvent(dspy,&event);
            return 1;
        } else if (event.type==ButtonPress) {
            XPutBackEvent(dspy,&event);
            return 1;
        }
    } /* <<=== added missing close-curly here */
    return 0;
}

char wait()
{
    XEvent event;
    XNextEvent(dspy,&event);
    if(event.type==KeyPress) {
        saved_x = event.xkey.x;
        saved_y = event.xkey.y;
        return XLookupKeysym(&event.xkey,0);
    } else if(event.type==ButtonPress) {
        saved_x = event.xkey.x;
        saved_y = event.xkey.y;
        return event.xbutton.button;
    }
}
```

And then they are called in the main like so,

```
if (event_waiting()){
  char c = wait();
  //Switch case goes here
}
```

EDIT 2: UPDATED CODE

```
XEvent event;
if(XCheckMaskEvent(display,-1,&event)) 
{
    if(event.type==KeyPress) {
        XPutBackEvent(display,&event);
        return 1;
    } else if (event.type==ButtonPress) {
        XPutBackEvent(display,&event);
        return 1;
    }
}
XFlush(display);
return 0;
```

`

Comment: Without seeing any code/information about how your library works it's almost impossible to tell you what's wrong...

Comment: `event_waiting` was missing a close-curly. I hope I put it in the right spot. And `char wait()` is missing a return value if neither a KeyPress nor a ButtonPress is present, a UB condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lag, which gets worse over time, means that you have many untouched events in your event queue, which slows down `XCheckMaskEvent()`.

Try specifying events using `XSelectInput(... ButtonPressMask | KeyPressMask)`, and try flushing the event queue using `XFlush()` if there is no event in which you are interested:

```
    if(event.type==KeyPress) {
        XPutBackEvent(dspy,&event);
        return 1;
    } else if (event.type==ButtonPress) {
        XPutBackEvent(dspy,&event);
        return 1;
    } else {
        XFlush(dspy); // this
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I had one question though. How would I go about flushing them? I think I would have to add something before the `return 0;`in `event_waiting()` but I'm not quite sure what.

Comment: Thanks again for your edit. I did as you suggested, but I am still experiencing significant (though perhaps not as great?) lag. Any other suggestions?

Comment: `XFlush()` alone might be not sufficient. If event consuming routine takes time then the number of waiting events can be high. So it's better to filter input events using `XSelectInput()` also.

Comment: XFlush only flushes the outgoing queue, not the incoming :P